# How to implement picking point by mouse under paraview web

Tags: vtk, paraview

Our company want our paraview web application to show relevant data when users click left mouse button.

The other part like how to extract data from a selected point was straightforward. But I cannot solve the problem: how to pick a point in the coordinates while mouse click?

I added a callback function to handle left button press in the python script. And then I tried to use an *vtkPointPicker* to cast a ray and pick the point in the coordinates. But the *pvpython* program which run the python script as the server will crash when click mouse (to be exact when the picker run *pick()*). Under debugging I found that the VTK code dereferencing null pointer was why the program crash. But the VTK source code is just too complicated to delve into further.

Here is my callback function:

```
def CustomLeftButtonPress(obj, event):
    x = obj.GetEventPosition()[0]
    y = obj.GetEventPosition()[1]

    picker = vtkPointPicker()
    obj.SetPicker(picker)
    currentRenderer = obj.FindPokedRenderer(x,y)
    picker.Pick(x, y, 0.0, currentRenderer)
    ...
```

`picker.Pick(x, y, 0.0, currentRenderer)` causes the crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should use `vtkWorldPointPicker` instead of `vtkPointPicker`.